# Questions about local database vs service-based database

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I have a some questions about local and service-based databases: Does using a service-based database require the user to have SQL Server installed? If so, is there ANY way around it? Does a local database require the user to have SQL Server installed? What is the difference between a local database and a service-based database. (I am talking about the items in Visual Studio)

Comment: What is the point of having a service based database if you need to have it installed locally? Plus, can you be more specific? Which service are you talking about?

Comment: @Moron: I think he means the "service-based database" item in Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm talking about. Sorry, I did't know what it was called outside Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clients do not need SQL installed to programatically connect to a database located elsewhere.  Whatever mechanism contains the code to connect to databases in general will create the connection.  For example, the System.Data namespace of .NET takes care of this for .NET programs.  SQL installation is not necessary.  Management tools, of course, will not be present on the client.